# Drawing a smooth curve in SFML

Tags: c++, math, graphics, 2d, sfml

I am building a program in C++ using the SFML library which plots mathematical functions such as f(x)=sin(x). The code used to plot the points is:

```
VertexArray curve(PrimitiveType::LineStrip, 100);
for (int x = -50; x < 50; x++)
{
    curve.append(Vertex(Vector2f(x,- sin(x))));
}
```

This code produces this plot:

[image]

As you can see the plot is not smooth and is made up of short lines due to sf::Linestrip. Is there a way to ( in SFML ) make this plot smoother ( e.g by shortening the line segments )?
Any feedback is much appreciated : ).

Comment: Have you tried to enable antialising for the window via [`ContextSettings`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/structsf_1_1ContextSettings.php)?

Comment: You're only plotting in increments of `1`. Try incrementing by a smaller number to get more points on the curve. You can change your loop to `for (float x = -50.0f; x < 50.0f; x+=.25f)` as a quick test.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I just tried and it doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option is to increase the resolution of the lines - i.e. have **more**, **smaller** lines. This is simple to achieve and may be acceptable for your use case.

[Sean Cline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020072/sean-cline)'s example in the comments should be a good starting point:

```
for (float x = -50.0f; x < 50.0f; x += .25f)
{
    curve.append(Vertex(Vector2f(x,- sin(x))));
}
```

You can then easily generalize the *range* and *step* and play around with the values:

```
float min_range = -200.f;
float max_range = 200.f;
float step = 0.5f;

for (float x = min_range; x < max_range ; x += step)
{
    curve.append(Vertex(Vector2f(x,- sin(x))));
}
```

Finally, you can abstract this away behind a nice interface:

```
using precision = float;

struct plot_params
{
    precision _min_range;
    precision _max_range;
    precision _step;
};

template <typename TFunction>
auto plot(const plot_params pp, TFunction&& f)
{
    assert(pp._min_range <= pp._max_range);
    assert(pp._step > 0.f);

    VertexArray curve(PrimitiveType::LineStrip, 
        std::ceil((pp._max_range - pp._min_range) / pp._step);

    for (auto x = pp._min_range; x < pp._max_range; x += pp._step)
    {
        curve.append(Vertex(f(x)));
    }
}
```

And you can use `plot` as follows:

```
const auto my_params = []
{
    plot_params pp;
    pp._min_range = -200.f;
    pp._max_range = 200.f;
    pp._step = 0.5f;
    return pp;
})();

auto curve = plot(my_params, 
                  [](auto x){ return Vector2f(x,- sin(x)); });
```

Comment: Haha I tried the first option earlier but my code was not working. But @SeanCline seemed to fix this issue with his for loop.

Comment: Thankyou for the link on bezier curves though. I'll research into them.

Comment: Using Bezier Curves doesn't make any sense here, because rather than interpolating points between you should just use your actual formula. You'll have to calculate/draw the vertices anyway, so just do it right straight away..

Comment: @Mario: true, more points from the original formula can always generated with more resolution. For some reason I was thinking of an unrelated situations where the points are already given. Updating the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense, if you'd have n points and should show a graph for them.

Comment: Side question: Why construct the parameters inside a lambda? Seems unnecessarily complex, please someone explain

Comment: @defense2000x: it allows you to mark `my_params` as `const`.